# Pandas Crosstab with Percentage calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, crosstab

I have a python dataframe as below. I want to do crosstab/pivot with percentage calculation as below.

```
owner = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
user = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
used_hours = [75,25,0,500,250,250,400,50,50]
available_hours = [100,100,100,1000,1000,1000,500,500,500]
data = {'Owner':owner,'User':user,'used_hours':used_hours,'available_hours':available_hours}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

[image]

Current Output:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df["Owner"], df["User"], normalize='index')
```

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Please post your data as text, not pictures.

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**.

Comment: What have you done? StackOverflow  is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some post formatting here, but define your own `to_percent` function and aggregate on that:

```
def to_percent(x):
    return x * 100
print(pd.crosstab(df.Owner, df.User, values=(df.used_hours / df.available_hours), aggfunc=to_percent))
```

outputs:

```
User      a     b     c
Owner
a      75.0  25.0   0.0
b      50.0  25.0  25.0
c      80.0  10.0  10.0
```